# What is meant by $A_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A_4$ be the alternating group.

What is then meant by
$$
A_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2?
$$

I think, $\mathbb{Z}_{2}=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Most likely, it's the direct product of the alternating group on $4$ elements and a cyclic group of order $2$, as you hinted at. It could mean something else too but this is by far the most likely.

Comment: Yes. Or the (multiplicative) group $\{1,-1\}$.. So  $A_4\times \mathbf Z_2$ is the set of pairs $(\sigma,1)$ or $(\sigma, -1)$ where $\sigma$ is an even permutation of $4$ elements.

Comment: @Bernard: You wouldn't write $\mathbb Z_2$ for $\{-1,1\}$, though -- even though the two groups are isomorphic.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: It was just for the multiplicative notation on both factors. That said, I certainly wouldn't write $\mathbf F_3^\times$!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb Z_2$, in this context, is the additive group of integers modulo $2$ -- that is, the set $\{0,1\}$ with the operation $\oplus$:
$$ 0\oplus 0 = 0 \\ 0\oplus 1 = 1 \\ 1 \oplus 0 = 1 \\ 1\oplus 1=0 $$

$A_4\times \mathbb Z_2$ is then simply a (direct) *product of group* -- that is, its elements are ordered pairs of an even permutation of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and an element of $\{0,1\}$, and the group operation combines each side of the pairs separately.

Comment: Is $A_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2=S_4$? If yes, how can I see this?

Comment: @Rhjg: No, they are different groups, even though they both have $24$ elements. For example, $S_4$ contains several elements of order $4$; $A_4\times \mathbb Z_2$ has none.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Another way to see this is that $A_4\times\mathbb Z_2$ has a normal subgroup of order $2$, while $S_4$ has no normal subgroup of order $2$, because a subgroup is normal iff. it is a union of conjugacy classes. If $S_4$ has such normal subgroup of order $2$, there are $2$ distinct conjugacy classes of size $1$, which means that $Z(S_4)>1$, contradiction.

Comment: LOL, thinking of $Z(S_4)$, I noticed that yet another way to show this is that $Z(S_4)=1$ while $Z(A_4\times\mathbb Z_2)=Z(A_4)\times Z(\mathbb Z_2)\cong\mathbb Z_2$